# Unity : Porting Animation from Maya

Tags: python, animation, unity-game-engine, maya, curve

I have an Animation porting from Maya, in the animation there are something i need to toggle the image on and off, I do it by setting the scale to 0 for off, 1 for on. But in unity it would automatically add some smooth curve in-between keyframe, which i do not need it, while i know i can manually set it to constant in unity but this is not the best solution since I have many other animation.

Is there any better solution for this? is there any setting in Maya so that unity would know which keyframe need to be constant?

[image: This is the curve in-between keyframe]

Comment: Did you bake the animation? I think that if you bake the animation in Maya it should come into Unity as it is.

Comment: yea i tried bake it but unity will add the curve in between keyframe anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is to use `Visibility` boolean parameter instead of `Scale` in the Channel Box. Write in Script Editor:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.setAttr( 'pPlane1.visibility', 0 )
```

[image]

1. To export Maya scene to Unity project, just choose:

`File > Send to Unity > Set Unity Project`, then browse to select a valid, local Unity project (the project directory) and click Select. You need to set the project only once.

Then select `File > Send to Unity`, and select `All` or `Selection`.
In the Export window that appears, enter a name to save the scene as a `.fbx` file in your Unity project's Assets folder.

2. OR here's one more possible solution: "The better way is to simply save the Maya `.ma` file in your project folder (don't bake the animation in the Maya file) and then choose to bake animations in the Unity import settings. Unity will automatically convert the file into `.fbx` and then into Unity's data format in the background".

[Unity forum: Exporting Maya Animation to Unity3d](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/13200/exporting-maya-animation-to-unity3d.html)

For saving Maya scene using Python just type in Script Editor:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.file( rename='forUnity.ma' )
cmds.file( save=True, type='mayaAscii' )
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, unfortunately i don't think there is anything i can do using this visibility parameter, i still couldn't fix the issue other than setting them constant manually.